# How to get std::deque pointer to the raw data?

Tags: c++, std

I know for std::vector, std::vector:  data() and &something[0]  are both OK, what about std::deque? 
There is no data() function for std::deque.

Edit:  if std::deque is not guaranteed to use contiguous storage, how do i implement a deque that can get the raw data ?

Comment: std::deque is not guaranteed to use contiguous storage. Thus there may not be an array of raw data to get the pointer to.

Comment: *"how do i implement to a deque that can get the raw data?"* -- That makes no sense, please rephrase it.

Comment: Why do you think you need "the raw data"? What are you actually hoping to do?

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely A function(interface) need a array

Comment: @user3793905, then you can't get it from `deque`, there is no array. Either don't use `deque` or copy the elements out into something like a `vector`

Answer (score 5):

The data contained in deque is not guaranteed to be placed in continuous memory block. This means that there could not be function similar to data() of vector.

Answer (score 3):

No, the double-ended queue is a dynamically growing data structure. Unlike the std::vector it is not layed-out in memory like an array but as arbitrary memory locations pointing to the previous and to the next memory section.